# Use of undeclared identifier

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors, xcode6, nsobject

I am learning objective-C programming from The Big Nerd Ranch Guide 2nd edition book.  I have gotten to chapter 18 with ease but now that Xcode updated I am experiencing the syntax error "use of undeclared identifier 'heightInMeters'. Here is my code which is objective-c with a subclass of NSObject.

```
***AppDelegate.h***
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

{
    // BNRPerson has two instance variables
    float _heightInMeters;
    int _weightInKilos;
}
// BNRPerson has methods to read and set its instance variables
- (float)heightInMeters;
- (void)setHeightInMeters:(float)h;
- (int)weightInKilos;
- (void)setWeightInKilos:(int)w;

// BNRPerson has a method that calculates the Body Mass Index
- (float)bodyMassIndex;

@end


***AppDelegate.m***
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    - (float)heightInMeters *USE OF UNDECLARED IDENTIFIER 'heightInMeters'
    {
        return _heightInMeters;
    }
    - (void)setHeightInMeters:(float)h
    {
        _heightInMeters=h;
    }
    - (int)weightInKilos
    {
        return _weightInKilos;
    }
    - (void)setWeightInKilos:(int)w
    {
        _weightInKilos=w;
    }
    - (float)bodyMassIndex
    {
        return _weightInKilos / (_heightInMeters * _heightInMeters);
    }
 }

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
     // Insert code here to tear down your application
}

@end
```

Comment: What is this supposed to be: `- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    - (float)heightInMeters *USE OF UNDECLARED IDENTIFIER 'heightInMeters'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are putting methods inside a method. I don't know why. Try:

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  Test
//
//  Created by JK on 11/23/14.
//  
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

}

- (float)heightInMeters
{
    return _heightInMeters;
}

- (void)setHeightInMeters:(float)h
{
    _heightInMeters=h;
}

- (int)weightInKilos
{
    return _weightInKilos;
}

- (void)setWeightInKilos:(int)w
{
    _weightInKilos=w;
}

- (float)bodyMassIndex
{
    return _weightInKilos / (_heightInMeters * _heightInMeters);
}


- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}

@end
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question this code works in the compiler. Your help saved me a lot of time looking over my syntax thank you for your time.

Comment: Showing your thanks by accepting my answer will help me, you, and the SO community :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your method implementations out of applicationDidFinishLaunching:

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

 }

- (float)heightInMeters
    {
        return _heightInMeters;
    }
- (void)setHeightInMeters:(float)h
    {
        _heightInMeters=h;
    }
- (int)weightInKilos
    {
        return _weightInKilos;
    }
- (void)setWeightInKilos:(int)w
    {
        _weightInKilos=w;
    }
- (float)bodyMassIndex
    {
        return _weightInKilos / (_heightInMeters * _heightInMeters);
    }

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
     // Insert code here to tear down your application
}
```